# Buttons on top of TextInput Element is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make visible list of buttons on top of a multi-line text input, which is now working. But when i am clicking on one of these button nothing is happening.

I am using zIndex to bring the childComponent on top of TextInput, Now when i am clicking on these button TextInput is getting focus instead of triggering button click event.

I just started learning react-native so I am not able to understand where i need to make the changes for making it functional.

Sample Code structure given below:*

```
const Component_1=()=>{

const UpdateTextInput=(ip,callType)=>{
console.log(ip);

}
return (<View keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handle'}>

<View style={{flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'#fff',zIndex:10}}>
<ChildComponent callBackFunc={(ip,callType)=>UpdateTextInput(ip,callType)} />
</View>


<View>
<TextInput
multiline
onChangeText={(text)=>updateString(text,'')}
/>
</View>

</View>
)
}



export default Component_1;

        
const ChildComponent=({callBackFunc})=>{

const [ButtonSection,SetButtonSection]=useState(false)

return (
    
<View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>


<View style={{flexDirection:'column',width:'15%',position:'absolute'}}  >
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>SetButtonSection(!ButtonSection)} style={{borderColor:'tomato',borderEndWidth:1}}>
<Icon
name='arrow-drop-down'
size={25}
type='material'
iconStyle={{color:'tomato',textAlign:'center',paddingHorizontal:20,paddingVertical:8,fontSize:20}}
/>
</TouchableOpacity>
{ButtonSection==true
?<View style={{flexDirection:'column',position:'relative',backgroundColor:'#ccc'}}>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>callBackFunc('','CLR')} style={{borderColor:'tomato',borderEndWidth:1}}>
<Icon
name='block'
size={25}
type='material'
iconStyle={{color:'tomato',textAlign:'center',paddingHorizontal:10,paddingVertical:8,fontSize:20}}

/>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>callBackFunc('','COPY')} style={{borderColor:'tomato',borderEndWidth:1}}>
  
<Icon
name='content-copy'
size={25}
type='material'
iconStyle={{color:'tomato',textAlign:'center',paddingHorizontal:10,paddingVertical:8,fontSize:20}}
/>
</TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>callBackFunc('','SAVE')} style={{borderColor:'tomato',borderEndWidth:1}}>
<Icon
name='save'
size={25}
type='material'
iconStyle={{color:'tomato',textAlign:'center',paddingHorizontal:10,paddingVertical:8,fontSize:20}}

/>
</TouchableOpacity>

<Button title='BTN' onPress={()=>console.log('Button1')
}/>
</View>
:null
}
</View>

<ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}  keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handle'} style={{marginRight:50}}>
    <Item/>
</ScrollView>

</View>
)

}

export default ChildComponent
```

[image: I am trying this]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using zIndex, use absolute position in view.
`position: 'absolute'`

Give absolute position to the view of child component